# How to use "on the other side of the ledger" in a sentence?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

Some where, I have read an author use a sentence like "However, on the other side of the ledger" while talking about disadvantages of a proposed solution. How to use that phrase in a sentence without sounding "awkward"?

Answer (score 1):

Awkwardness (and even "awkwardness") may be in the eye of the beholding reader, but I think this passage from From [*A Little Corner of Freedom: Russian Nature Protection from Stalin to Gorbachev*](https://books.google.com/books?id=2rRjx4pCEx0C&pg=PA288&dq=%22other%20side%20of%20the%20ledger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI8bzkyfbKAhXKOz4KHbR1AtE4KBDoAQhGMAc#v=onepage&q=%22other%20side%20of%20the%20ledger%22&f=false) by D R Weiner gracefully balances the good and the bad in the life of former Soviet premiere Nikita Khrushchev:

> Russians and the world remember him [Khrushchev] with gratitude as the
>   man who courageously informed us of the crimes of the Stalin era,
>   freed perhaps eight million prisoners from the labor camps, allowed
>   the publication of Solzhenitsyn's *One Day in the Life of Ivan
>   Denisovich*, and opened the USSR to the world community, even if only
>   haltingly. **On the other side of the ledger**, it is impossible to
>   recall Khrushchëv without a shuddering remembrance of the Cuban
>   missile crisis, the Berlin Wall, the suppression of the Hungarian
>   Revolution, his personal support of T. D. Lysenko, and his
>   mismanagement of Soviet agriculture.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=other%20side%20of%20the%20ledger&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cother%20side%20of%20the%20ledger%3B%2Cc0) its usage has decreased in recent decades. It probably sounds "awkward" because of the use of the outdated term "[ledger](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ledger)" with reference to accounting practices.

> - On the other side of the ledger, the firm reportedly filed hundreds of faked voter registration forms in Florida this year. (Dictionary.com)

- The expression may sound formal rather than awkward, a more common alternative is "[on the other hand](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=other%20side%20of%20the%20ledger%2Con%20the%20other%20hand&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cother%20side%20of%20the%20ledger%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20other%20hand%3B%2Cc0)".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/165270)

Comment: @macraf - The OP's usage is perfectly idiomatic, and if it "sounds awkward" to the OP it's because he's not familiar with it.  Josh's answer is appropriate.